# google chrome closes comments during spell checking

Tags: bug

I prefer not to use the mouse when typing, I'm using the keyboard. (typing with the mouse is no fun.) I tend to think faster than I type so I sometimes get letters out of position. Spellchecker to the rescue. Google chrome puts these nice little squiggles under words that I need to look at closer. Now sometimes I don't know the right spelling for a word so I pop up the context menu and look for the right spelling, move to it and press enter. This is where things break. The enter key event is also interpreted as the end of the comment and it is closed. I was not finished yet.

Comment: See also [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I am aware of that (mis)feature, and once I got used to it it is ok, but not in the context menu.